# Best way to get HATEOAS links onInit() angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

Hi I want to know what is the best practice to get links form Spring Data REST HATEOAS in angular 4 at the start of my application.
My api endpoint has the list of all links and I want to save it in a name-value map at the start of application.
for example:

```
`{
  "_links" : {
    "ticketTypes" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/ticketTypes{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated" : true
    },
    "depositReceipts" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/depositReceipts{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated" : true
    },
    "transitCertificates" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/transitCertificates{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated" : true
    }
}`
```

In onInit() of my main application component I do the call to retrieve the entire list and it works.
In order to follow HATEOAS principles, I should not create by hands endpoints url. What I should do is retrieve the URI I need reading it from my hashmap.
Unfortunately I can't do this in a simple way because each component could attempt to make a REST call before my hashmap with urls is created.

This is the service method that retrieve the URLs list:

```
getLinks() {

    this.http.get(this.url, this.http.setCommonOption())
    .map((response: Response) => response.json());
      .subscribe(response => {

        this.linksMap = response._links;

        (<any>Object).entries(this.linksMap).forEach(
          ([key, value]) => {console.log(key, value);
            this.linksMap2.push(new Link(key, value.href));
         }
        );
        console.log(this.linksMap2);
        this.charge = 1;
      })
  }
```

I'm wondering if there is a best practice to solve my problem.

Comment: why not move all this into a service that is able to read and give the URLs to the rest of the application?

Comment: Yes It is a service that retrieve the URLs, I update my question